# Understanding Safe.Coerce in Purescript

Tags: purescript

I've been looking at the compiled version of some code snippets to dig into how my code is represented at runtime.

I'm not surprised to see that safe coerce and unsafe coerce are the same in the compiled JavaScript. There's a dictionary passed into safe coerce that's unused/undefined in the code I've looked at so far.

It seems like if the runtime representation of two types is the same, then there shouldn't be any runtime overhead for having/using such a type. This isn't true and I'm curious to understand why.

Coercing two types requires a function call at runtime. What I'm not understanding is that this function call appears to do nothing.

```js
exports.unsafeCoerce = function (x) {
  return x;
};
```

---

If I declare a newtype

```hs
newtype Selection = Selection Int
```

I see something similar in JavaScript:

```js
var Selection = function (x) {
  return x;
};
```

Which means I might see something like this in JavaScript:

```js
return Selection(Data_Int.pow(2)(Safe_Coerce.coerce()(n) - 1 | 0));
```

which should be identical to this:

```js
return Data_Int.pow(2)(n - 1 | 0);
```

In this case, both `Selection` and `coerce` only ever return what they're given. Once the type checking has been done, I'm not sure what purpose they continue to serve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the code is generated like it is, and not in a more efficient form like you suggest, is because the purs compiler has only a simplistic optimiser.

Why unsafeCoerce is defined as it is is because it is a PureScript function and must match the runtime representation of PureScript functions. Same goes for `Selection`.

Constraints are represented as functions on dictionaries. Some time ago there was an optimisation added such that empty dictionaries do not have to be constructed as empty JavaScript objects, and instead can be represented by `undefined`. That is why there is no argument passed to `coerce`.